# How to create large readonly entities in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have an entity with around 20 properties. Following DDD, I want to make setters private and allow mutation only through methods, since there are some rules I have to check.

But how should these entities being created? Should they have a constructor with 20 parameters? Should I create an intermediate writable entity that is passed in the constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is sensible depends ultimately on the case and the context. Options include

- an intermediate writeable entity
- some intermediate entities from which the final object gets constructed
- a constructor providing default values for most of the 20 parameters (and methods to change the remaining one afterwards)
- an internal [Builder class](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2)
- a mixture of all the above.

Note this question has pretty much nothing to do with DDD, and it is best not to think in terms of anonymous classes out of their context, but to make decisions based on the actual classes, their names and abstractions, and the requirements you have.

Comment: I will go with the builder class. Thanks very much.